# Openvpn execute script on client-connect with restricted user

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to execute a command on my openvpn-server every time a client connects. I have an user openvpn that was created by using

```
adduser --system --shell /usr/sbin/nologin --no-create-home openvpn
groupadd openvpn
usermod -g openvpn openvpn
```

This user is used in my server config (and you also see the command I want to execute on every client-connect):

```
... <parts omitted>
user openvpn
group openvpn

client-connect '/bin/bash -c "sudo /usr/local/psa/bin/dns -a my.domain -a $common_name -ip $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip"'
script-security 2
```

I also added an entry via visudo (openvpn ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/psa/bin/dns) to make the script executable for openvpn with sudo.
The server starts without errors, but if a client (in this log with the name server03) connects, the script fails with the following log:

```
sudo[31369]:  openvpn : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/etc/openvpn ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/psa/bin/dns -a my.domain -a server03 -ip 10.9.0.2
sudo[31369]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sudo[31369]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
ovpn-user-server[31357]: server03/87.XXX.XXX.4:40594 WARNING: Failed running command (--client-connect): external program exited with error status: 1
```

As you can see in the logs the command is executed with the right variables, but somehow fails. But if I execute the command (as root) from the CMD, it terminates successfully and also if I log into the openvpn-user via

```
su -s /bin/bash openvpn
```

the script also terminates successfully. Log:

```
openvpn@...:/etc/openvpn$ sudo /usr/local/psa/bin/dns -a my.domain -a server03 -ip 10.9.0.2
SUCCESS: Creation of DNS record in Domain 'my.domain' complete.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sudo as a default require TTY. Once you run the script manually TTY is availbale. Once it is run in cron or (I guess also) by openvpn as called script there is no TTY available.

I see 2 options:

- try to rewrite the script to not need the root / sudo (e.g. nsupdate with TSIG)
- change configuration of sudo to not require tty [Why does cron silently fail to run sudo stuff in my script? (@stackexchange)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script):

  ```
  #Defaults    requiretty
  #Defaults   !visiblepw
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I never heard before of the default tty requirement. I looked in my /etc/sudoers file and the was no usage of requiretty. I also added "Defaults:openvpn !requiretty" to the file below my "openvpn ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/psa/bin/dns" line, but still the script is failing... Also "Defaults:root !requiretty" made no changes.

Comment: let try two more things... 1)How you know that it end up correctly once you run it manually? Did you try **echo $?** to see return code? 2)Let me one more analogy with cron. In case cron task produce any output (both output or error) it is send out as e-mail to user...Try to change the script to not produce any output - I see the confirmation about adding the records in manual run.It may be that the output could be interpreted as **not normal** exit status.In Openvpn documentation is mentioned that valid config output is send back via the file provided as "last perameter" while run the script.